# mongodb error: 'longitude/latitude is out of bounds

Tags: mongodb

when I run the mongoDB query, I get error which is  'longitude/latitude is out of bounds.

Here is my query is created:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("loc",
            new BasicDBObject("$geoWithin",
                    new BasicDBObject("$geometry",
                            new BasicDBObject("type","Polygon").append("coordinates", polygon))));
```

Here is my mongoDB query:

```
db.collection_name.find(
   { "loc" : 
        { "$geoWithin" : 
            { "$geometry" : 
                { "type" : "Polygon" , "coordinates" : [ [ [ 44.67047 , 136.01075] , [ 77.05318 , 33.59619] , [ 13.04135 , -22.31323]]]

                }
            }
        }
   } 
)
```

I get this error output:

```
{
"code" : {
    "_bsontype" : "Int32",
    "value" : 2
},
"codeName" : "BadValue",
"errmsg" : "longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 44.6705 lat: 136.011",
"message" : "longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 44.6705 lat: 136.011",
"name" : "MongoError",
"ok" : {
    "_bsontype" : "Double",
    "value" : 0
},
```

How can I solve this problem ? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Those are invalid coordinates. Use the correct coordinates as the error is suggesting. I hope you are not mixing up lat with long. Try switching the values of lat and long.

Comment: @Veeram when I use like it, I get same error.

Comment: You get same error when you use `db.collection_name.find(
   { "loc" : 
        { "$geoWithin" : 
            { "$geometry" : 
                { "type" : "Polygon" , "coordinates" : [ [ [ 136.01075, 44.67047 ] , [ 77.05318 , 33.59619] , [ 13.04135 , -22.31323]]]

                }
            }
        }
   } 
)` ?

Comment: @Veeram No, I got error which is "Loop is not closed"

Answer (score 1):

> "longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 44.6705 lat: 136.011"

You need to specify in the order of longitude then latitude. The valid range of latitude in degrees is `-90` and `+90`. Your value of latitude of `136.011` is out of range.

> "Loop is not closed"

To specify geospatial query for [$geometry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geometry/) you need to close the [GeoJSON Polygon](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygon) loop in order to create a polygon shape.

For example:

```
{
  type: "Polygon",
  coordinates: [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0  ] ] ]
}
```

Note that the first and last coordinates are matching, in order to close the polygon shape.

The above is assuming that you're referring to [GeoJSON polygons with a single ring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygons-with-a-single-ring).